# How do I get rid of all caps ribbon titles in Office 2013?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013

Installed Office 2013 on Windows 8 today. It's great, except for one thing, the all caps ribbon titles are inconsistent with the title case titles everywhere else in Windows 8. Is there a registry setting that will let me change this?

[image: consistency]

Comment: If this had been a less advanced piece of software, I'd suggested looking into the EXE using a hex editor or resource editor, but considering this is Microsoft Office, I'd recommend against this. It might cause all sorts of havoc.

Comment: You're right, it's horrible. The status bar is also in all caps too.

Comment: upvoted as a protest to Microsoft bad taste.

Answer (score 42):

Of course, it can be fixed. Simply put a space before or after the Tab title. I prefer putting it after.

- Right click the tab heading > Customize the ribbon > Click on the tab you want to rename.
  Either right click and select "Rename" or click the "Rename" button below.
- Then put a space before or after the tab title.
- The tab title will now appear in sentence case.

Comment: I've undeleted this, but it would be nice to [edit] your answer to include all the steps necessary to do this. If your answer doesn't appear to actually answer the question, you should probably expand it and make it more descriptive.

Comment: Albeit a clunky workaround, this works, and now they're nice again *subjective!* All but "File"

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I click to rename it doesn't respond.

Comment: See [Zonder's answer](http://superuser.com/a/521561/986) for a link to his batch file that automates the process of modifying the menu names in all the Office applications.  Quite a time saver.

Comment: I have the same problem as Yuck - right-click, Rename, nothing happens; same if you use the Rename button below. However, Zonder's download worked great.

Comment: THis is the best answer. no download, scripts or anything :)

Comment: @Yuck did you append *space* after name as is written in this response?

Comment: Up vote this answer given that @Zonder solution is no longer viable (download not available).

Answer (score 19):

No, apparently, there isn't. Here is what seems to be an official answer from Microsoft ([thread)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officedevpreview/thread/39b4b762-5ffa-4306-8c6a-7811d022334a):

> The development team discussed changing the tabs to proper case, but made a firm decision that **they would leave them all caps as designed**. There is no way to change them in the registry, but if you have an add-in that creates new tabs, they will be whatever case you specify in your custom ribbon file.

There is a registry setting to disable all caps menu in the Visual Studio 2012 (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859173/how-to-disable-all-caps-menu-titles-in-visual-studio-2012-rc), for example):

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\General
>   DWORD: SuppressUppercaseConversion
>   Value: 1

But this does not work for the new Office 2013. Just in case I have tried these settings (of course, none of them worked):

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\SuppressUppercaseConversion
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\General  \SuppressUppercaseConversion

If you need more information on this choice, here is a good thread at [ux.stackexchange.com](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/22258/whats-the-deal-with-windows-8-elements-with-all-caps), where you can find a designer's opinion on that.

Comment: On that SE thread I found the following quote from MS: "We've chosen to use uppercase styling in the top menu for two main reasons: 1) to keep Visual Studio consistent with the direction of other Microsoft user experiences". *Really*? What the beep's up with the Win8 UI then if they wanted to maintain visual consistency?

Comment: Microsoft made a lot of changes in Windows 8. They wouldn't want to risk loosing market share by pushing all the planned changes at once.

Comment: Microsoft has never kept Office or their other apps consistent with the OS. They tend to be a testbed for UI ideas.

Comment: if we can't get rid of the caps, can we change the font to something that doesn't look so caps-y?

Comment: This answer is incorrect; there is, in fact, a workaround to this horrible design: http://superuser.com/a/495227/6714

Comment: @Tullo: [This answer](http://superuser.com/a/521561/986) is even better.

Comment: The funny/moronic part is that Windows 8, despite its flaws, didn't go around capitalizing assorted parts of the UI for zero benefit. (The caps don't convey any info, they just make it look worse. The beta of Office2013 even had the mailbox name in all caps - at least they backed off on that one.)

Answer (score 6):

You can also try unOFFIC (http://unoffic.migeel.sk/). It's a small in-memory patch for all Office 2013 apps that fixes ALL CAPS not only on the ribbon, but also in the status bar and a few other spots. It doesn't modify the Office EXEs in any way, so it should be pretty safe and update resilient.

Answer (score 4):

The all-caps is a software feature. The new release of Visual Studio 2012 uses all-caps as well. Microsoft is probably testing if users accept this new look. Depending on how things turn out, they'll probably release a patch (service packs) to either change all-caps to normal (Office, Visual Studio, etc) or normal to all-caps (File Explorer, etc).

[image]

Comment: Note that Vladimir's answer points out a way to change this in Visual Studio.

Comment: There is option to make Visual Studio IDE into normal case, by editing registry.

Answer (score 4):

right click on the tab title, choose customize ribbon, click rename and put a blank space in front of the tab title. Click OK. Do the same for all the other titles.

Comment: Does it really allow you to do that to default tabs like File, Edit? I'm pressing Rename and nothing happens.

Answer (score 4):

A Microsoft MVP has complete menu customization files available for download, here:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2013_release-office_install/proper-case-for-office-2013-ribbon-menus/d28ad27b-a727-4b63-a6e1-46deb15696a8

These can be safely imported into Office 2013 apps through the "Import/Export" feature in the ribbon customization menus, and they will proper-case the entire menu.