# Last letter missing from Excel Menu texts

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, context-menu, characters

I have a bizarre bug in Excel 2013. Every time I open a menu of any kind, the last letter or character of the menu's text is missing.

[image: Example: 'Go to special' Menu]

While the bug is not a problem in any way, I'm insanely curious as to what could cause such behavior, and wanted to know if anyone else has had this happen to them.

The bug may be related to changing the names of the Ribbon headers. Since I don't like them in ALLCAPS, I edited them to have their names in Proper Case, while adding an extra Space at the end [otherwise they would not change](https://superuser.com/questions/493836/how-do-i-get-rid-of-all-caps-ribbon-titles-in-office-2013). I think the bug started to happen after that, though I'm not sure. I tried changing the names back but it didn't help.

Re-installing would probably help, but this question is more out of curiosity than anything else.

Comment: What is your computer hardware specs? Screen resolution? Do you have magnification or scaling enabled on your display? Also, HOW did you modify the ribbon titles?

Comment: I modified them as is said in the link. They have the original names, but in proper case and with a space at the end. Screen resolution is 3840x2160. No magnification. Hardware: AMD Ryzen 5 1600 x6 core 3.2 GHz, Radeon RX 570, ASUS Prime B350M-A. But I don't know how any of that could help.